# How to do a log in without using a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, administration

I have a website in which I am setting up a log in for administrators to update content in the website. Normally I would do this with a php script and mySQL database. However, the hosting company I am using does not allow this type of thing used with their databases because it creates too much of a strain on their servers. That being said, is there another way to do a log in without using a database containing all the usernames and passwords?

Thanks!

Comment: *creates too much of a strain on their servers* ≈ *need new hosting company*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a non-public xml file to store usernames and passwords.

Comment: As stated below, sqlite or BDB would be a great idea as well. Maybe easier to work with than XML.

Answer (score 1):

Use a local configuration file (such as the XML file mentioned above) or use a BDB. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dba.php

Comment: the BDB or even sql lite would be a great solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic HTTP Authentication with PHP.  No database required.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php